# How to update a dictionary in a while loop?

Tags: python, loops

I am using two loops and cannot figure out how to properly update the dictionary in one loop and use it in the other loop.

In the first loop I am adding a new pair to the dictionary, but in the second loop I don't see any changes, how do I do it correctly?

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

dict_1 = {1:'1'}

def func_1():
    while True:
        dict_1.update({2:'2'})
        print('Result func_1-',dict_1)
        time.sleep(5)

def func_2():
    while True:
        print('Result func_2-',dict_1)
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=func_1) 
    p2 = Process(target=func_2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

`Result func_1- {1: '1', 2: '2'} Result func_2- {1: '1'}`

In the first cycle I see a new pair, but I do not see it in the second cycle.

Comment: Sharing data across processes is not trivial. What do you need this for?

Comment: do the heavy computation in separated Processes, return the result for each one, and then you can filter the results with a single process. It should be fast.

Comment: @tzaman In my case, in the first process, some functions are executed that return data, they need to be processed in another process.
I can write them to a file, but a dictionary would be the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by using `multiprocessing.Manager` to create a managed dictionary for your purpose this way:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

manager = Manager()
dict_1 = manager.dict({1:'1'})

def func_1():
    while True:
        dict_1.update({2:'2'})
        print('Result func_1-',dict_1)
        time.sleep(5)

def func_2():
    while True:
        print('Result func_2-',dict_1)
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=func_1) 
    p2 = Process(target=func_2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: Yes thank you! Using a manager did the trick for my problem!

Comment: @sdd You are welcome. Can you consider an upvote to the answer if you are satisfied with it?

Comment: I voted, but I have too little reputation for my vote to count)